# Preventing A Table From Stretching Vertically to Fill Table

Tags: html, css

I have a table that I have set heights for each row and a min height set for the whole table. The rows automatically stretch vertically to fill the whole table. How do I set the rows to not fill the entire table vertically. I want each row to be 40 pixels high. If there is only one row, there should be space underneath the row since the table is 200 pixels high. How do I prevent the rows from automatically filling the table vertically? I want the white space after the first row if there aren't any other rows

```css
<style>
    .messages {
        display:flex;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<div class="messages">
<div class="card w-75"">
    <h5 class="card-header py-3">Messages</h5>
    <div class="card-body" style="padding:0;">
        <table style="width:100%; min-height:200px; border: 1px solid; text-align: center; display:inline-table;">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="background-color:darkviolet; height:40px;">
                    <th style="color:white; border: 1px solid;">Date</th>
                    <th style="color:white; border: 1px solid;">Subject</th>
                    <th style="color:white; border: 1px solid;">From</th>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border: 1px solid; height:40px;">
                    <td style="border: 1px solid;">12/5/19</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid;">Test</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid;">John Doe</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="border: 1px solid; height:40px;">
                    <td style="border: 1px solid;">12/5/19</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid;">Test</td>
                    <td style="border: 1px solid;">Jane Doe</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" value="Test" style="height:40px; margin-left:20px; margin-top:60px;">Send A Message</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Move the `min-height` to the wrapping `div`.